# Routing to a specific view based upon a JSON return value in React using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

Let's say you have a JSON payload returning to a react application from an initial call after authentication to find out what "type" of role the user has and based upon this, they get routed to a specific view in React.  So from JSON I will receive something like this:

`{ "is_admin": true }`

In React Router, is there a way to test this value and then render the appropriate view? Basically looking at the JSON value and if they are an admin one collection of components are rendered,  if they not an admin, a different collection is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the router to send admin users to a specific url `http://mysite/admin` while other users go to `http://mysite/user`

In order to leverage the react-router , the best you can do here is use the `<Redirect />` component with something like that :

```
{ is_admin ? <Redirect to='/admin' /> : <Redirect to='/user' /> }
```